# C# Based Agent Development Framework

Tags: c#, frameworks, agent

A while ago I followed a course about Agent technology and we had to use JADE to learn the concept. Now i am wondering if there is any good and easy to use framework which is based on the C# language. If anyone knows a good framework please share the link.

Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: use* jade instead of try

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://oot.zcu.cz/NET_2003/Papers/Grosso.pdf) is a paper on a C# agent platform from University of Genova which could be a starting point for finding a framework.  You'll need to exercise your google skills....

Answer (score 1):

I found something similar to what you are looking for.

Check the below URLs.

boris.net might do the job.

http://www.alibojar.com/boris-net

https://www.scm.tees.ac.uk/isg/website/index.php?page=downloads_boris

Comment: Links are not enough to answer a question. Please, add the relevant information to your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at:

- http://www.alibojar.com/boris-net
- http://oellabs.com/aplodee3.aspx

There also this article that can be quite handy:

http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2004_10/article1/